Solution explanation for the question: Solve the equation $f(x, y, z, p, q) = z^2 - pqxy = 0$ using Charpit's method.
Solve the equation $f(x, y, z, p, q) = z^2 - pqxy = 0$ using Charpit's method.
My solution goes like this:
Given equation:
$f(x, y, z, p, q) = z^2 - pqxy = 0 \quad (1)$
Charpit's auxiliary equations:
$$\frac{dp}{f_x + pf_z} = \frac{dq}{f_y + qf_z} = \frac{dz}{-pf_p - qf_q} = \frac{dx}{-f_p} = \frac{dy}{-f_q}$$
From $(1):$
$$f_x = pqy, \quad f_y = pqx, \quad f_z = 2z, \quad f_p = -qxy, \quad f_q = -pxy$$
From $(2):$
$$\frac{dp}{-pqy + 2pz} = \frac{dq}{-pqx + 2qz} = \frac{dz}{2pqxy} = \frac{dx}{qxy} = \frac{dy}{pxy} \quad (3)$$
Each part of $(3):$
$\frac{xdp + pdx}{2pxz} = \frac{ydq + qdy}{2qyz}\implies
\frac{d(xp)}{xp} = \frac{d(yq)}{yq}
\implies 
log(px) = log(qy) + log(a^2)\implies
xp = a^2qy \quad (4)$
From $(1)$ and $(4):$
$$z^2 = (px)(qy) = a^2(qy)^2\implies 
qy = \frac{z}{a}.$$
So,
$$p = \frac{a^2qy}{x} = \frac{a^2}{x} \cdot \frac{z}{a} = \frac{az}{x}$$
Putting the values of p and q in $$dz = pdx + qdy:$$ we get,
$$dz = \frac{az}{x}dx + \frac{z}{ay}dy
\implies \frac{dz}{z} = a\frac{dx}{x} + \frac{1}{a}\frac{dy}{y}\implies 
log(z) = a \log(x) + \frac{1}{a} \log(y) + log(b)
z = x^a y^{\frac{1}{a}} b$$
This is the required complete integral.

However, I don't get how are they writing,

Each part of $(3):$
$\frac{xdp + pdx}{2pxz} = \frac{ydq + qdy}{2qyz}$

Can someone please explain this to me? I mean how are they getting the equation, $\frac{xdp + pdx}{2pxz} = \frac{ydq + qdy}{2qyz}$ from equation $(3)$ ?

The method is called componendo-dividendo and yields $$\frac{x dp}{-pqxy + 2pzx} = \frac{p dx}{pqxy} = \frac{x dp + p dx}{\require{cancel} \cancel{-pqxy} + 2pzx + \cancel{pqxy}}$$ Similarly for the other ratio equality.

@MathewCassel can we think it like this: Let equation $(3)$ be equal to $dt$ (say) and thus, $xdp=dt(-pqxy+2zpx)$ and $pdx=pqxydt$ and then adding the last two eqns we have, $\frac{xdp+pdx}{-pqxy+2pzx+pqxy}=dt=\frac{dx}{qxy}=\frac{dp}{-pqy+2pz}=...$ ---- and is this how we arrived at that equation, $\frac{xdp + pdx}{2pxz} = \frac{ydq + qdy}{2qyz}$ by doin the same thing for the other part?
